# Conveying the idea of "Elvis has left the building" (i.e. Sth has come to an end – it’s over)

Tags: expressions, traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_has_left_the_building

> Le sens que prend l'expression quand elle est réutilisée hors contexte
> est : « C'est fini, il n'y a plus rien à attendre, à espérer ». Son
> équivalent en français pourrait être « Les carottes sont cuites ! ».
> Elle est très peu utilisée traduite en français « Elvis a quitté le
> bâtiment » et assez rarement en dehors d'un public anglophone pour qui
> elle est une phrase punch line et une phrase fétiche très connue.

Wikipédia a-t-elle raison concernant la tournure française « Elvis a quitté le bâtiment »  ? L'équivalent français "Les carottes sont cuites !" est-il reconnu ? Quelles autres expressions rendent des idées similaires ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

« Les carottes sont cuites » veut dire que tout est fini, il n'y a plus d'espoir. Ça me semble en effet un bon équivalent pour *Elvis has left the building*.

L'expression employée dans ce sens est apparue au début XX<sup>e</sup> siècle.  Au XIX<sup>e</sup> « avoir ses carottes cuites » voulait dire qu'on était mourant.<sup>1</sup>

Je pense que l'expression est relativement populaire et que pratiquement tout le monde la comprend. Mais comme [le signale @jlliagre](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/39870/conveying-the-idea-of-elvis-has-left-the-building-i-e-sth-has-come-to-an-end/39872?noredirect=1#comment79456_39872) en commentaire l'expression s'est de nos jours raccourcie en « c'est cuit » et il est probable que c'est ce qui serait dit par les jeunes générations.  Elle est peut-être plus connue des plus âgés car elle était utilisée pendant la Seconde Guerre Mondiale sur Radio Londres pour annoncer des opérations, et est restée une expression fétiche dans ce contexte. C'est en particulier l'expression qui a servi à annoncer le Débarquement<sup>2</sup> <sup>3</sup>. Mais bien sûr elle n'était pas alors à prendre dans son sens habituel, c'était un code.

Quelques éléments supplémentaires [autour de l'expression](https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/origines/expression-les-carottes-sont-cuites/).

On propose parfois l'expression [c'est la fin des haricots](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/la-fin-des-haricots.php) comme équivalent mais ça me semble moins bien convenir que les carottes sont cuites.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Information qu'on trouve dans le *Dictionnaire culturel en langue française* mais qu'on trouve en beaucoup d'autres endroits.</sub> 
<sub><sup>2</sup> *D-Day*.</sub>
<sub><sup>3</sup> À écouter le  témoignage d'une membre de la [Direction des opérations spéciales](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Operations_Executive) pendant la Seconde Guerre mondiale qui attendait le message « les carottes sont cuites.</sub>

Comment: L'expression *les carottes sont cuites* semble passer un peu de mode chez les plus jeunes mais elle a engendré ***c'est cuit*** qui paraît toujours vivace.

Answer (score 2):

« les carottes sont cuites ! » introduit un glissement en cela que « Elvis has left the building. » indique la fin de quelque chose mais pas une fin dramatique, ce qui est le propre de cette première expression. Il existe une expression tout aussi familière qui est un équivalent exact : « C'est la fin des haricots. » ([réf.](https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/origines/expression-les-carottes-sont-cuites/)).

On peut voir [ici](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/elvis-has-left-the-building.html) que l'expression anglaise signifie seulement « La représentation est terminée ; il n'y a plus rien à dire. »

- It later took on the more general meaning of 'the show is over; there's nothing more to say'.

Toujours dans le registre familier ou très familier, on trouve l'expression suivante pour traduire cela plus exactement ; cependant, il n'existe pas de référence disant que c'est une expression employée généralement.

- Terminus, tout le monde descend.

Comment: @Fólkvangr Laquelle ?

Comment: @Fólkvangr Elle n'est pas proposée comme étant quelque chose de sûr ; je sais seulement que des gens l'utilisent : je n'ai pas de références. Donc, si quelqu'un, en particulier la personne qui a posé la question a le moyen de trouver une référence, ça fait une possibilité assurée ; autrement il n'y a aucun mal et rien de faux, puisque l'on vous averti qu'il n'y a pas de référence pour l'instant. En tout cas, je sais que ce qui pourrait constituer l'infime nombre de ses utilisateurs l'utilisent pour signifier « C'est la fin. », « C'est fini. ».

Comment: @Fólkvangr Vous voulez bien dire « figurativement » donc ;  vous confirmez alors implicitement avoir entendu cette expression dans des contextes autres que celles des fin de lignes d'autobus ou de métro ?